# Why does furthur execution halts after HttpResponse response=client.execute(request) line?

Tags: android, apache, api, http-response-codes

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.util.Log;

public class GetPostEx {

public String getInternetData() throws Exception{

    //String source_prog;
    //int lang_number;
    //BufferedReader in = null;
    String ret=null;
    try{

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("Some server link");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source", "print 1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lang", "5"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("testcases", "[\"1\"]"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", "Some key"));
         request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        Log.e("error", "before HTTPResponse");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        Log.e("error", "Aftr HTTPResponse");
        ret = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        }catch (Exception e){
            //Log.e("error","error!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}

}
```

and the code used in the other activity(AndroidHTTPRequestsActivity) from where i am calling my GetPostEx class is:-

```
GetPostEx test = new GetPostEx();
    try{
        returned = test.getInternetData();
} catch(Exception e){ 
            Log.e("error", "yo") ;
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am trying to make an android application which needs some HTTP Response from a server using API.This is my code for getting an HTTP response.But the execution halts after the line **HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);** The logcat is not displaying the error after this line whereas the one above it is getting displayed.
I am unable to figure out the reason behind this.

*The following lines are the stack trace details in logcat:-*

12-22 14:18:58.658: E/error(1335): before HTTPResponse

12-22 14:18:59.448: W/System.err(1335): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

12-22 14:18:59.448: W/System.err(1335):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)

12-22 14:18:59.458: W/System.err(1335):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)

12-22 14:18:59.458: W/System.err(1335):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)

12-22 14:18:59.458: W/System.err(1335):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)

12-22 14:18:59.458: W/System.err(1335) :      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)

12-22 14:18:59.458: W/System.err(1335):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)

12-22 14:18:59.458: W/System.err(1335):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)

12-22 14:18:59.478: W/System.err(1335):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)

12-22 14:18:59.478: W/System.err(1335):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)

12-22 14:18:59.478: W/System.err(1335):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)

12-22 14:18:59.478: W/System.err(1335):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)

12-22 14:18:59.478: W/System.err(1335):     at com.us.onlinecompilr.GetPostEx.getInternetData(GetPostEx.java:37)

12-22 14:18:59.478: W/System.err(1335):     at com.us.onlinecompilr.AndroidHTTPRequestsActivity.onCreate(AndroidHTTPRequestsActivity.java:29)

12-22 14:18:59.478: W/System.err(1335):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)

12-22 14:18:59.478: W/System.err(1335):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

12-22 14:18:59.478: W/System.err(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)

12-22 14:18:59.488: W/System.err(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)

12-22 14:18:59.488: W/System.err(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)

12-22 14:18:59.488: W/System.err(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)

12-22 14:18:59.488: W/System.err(1335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

12-22 14:18:59.488: W/System.err(1335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

12-22 14:18:59.488: W/System.err(1335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)

12-22 14:18:59.488: W/System.err(1335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

12-22 14:18:59.488: W/System.err(1335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

12-22 14:18:59.488: W/System.err(1335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)

12-22 14:18:59.488: W/System.err(1335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)

12-22 14:18:59.488: W/System.err(1335):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

12-22 14:18:59.588: I/Choreographer(1335): Skipped 641 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-22 14:19:03.278: I/Choreographer(1335): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-22 14:19:06.188: I/Choreographer(1335): Skipped 112 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: try putting a catch block too

Comment: well I modified the code as u said and have given the stack trace details also.

Comment: Problem is that you are making a network call in main thread. Use AsyncTask for making network call. see you error says 2-22 14:18:59.448: W/System.err(1335): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is clear

`2-22 14:18:59.448: W/System.err(1335): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

It simply means you are making network calls on main thread (UI thread).

Use AsynTask to make network calls. see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Another good example is http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/11/asynctask-android-example-asynctask-in.html

Answer (score 0):

It can happen that an exception is thrown in execute method. Hence the Log statement below execute will not be executed.

I see that you have written this code for Android. Check if you have INTERNET permission in your MANIFEST file.
Add a catch block and see the exception stacktrace.

Comment: I also feel so. But how to rectify it then?

Comment: Already added the INTERNET permission in manifest.

Comment: You need to add stack trace otherwise would be difficult to guess the problem.

Comment: well I modified the code as u said and have given the stack trace details also.